# Add new argument for all function instances used

Tags: c, eclipse

Im refactoring a legacy function and for adding a new argument in the existing function, I have to manually add it to all instances.
Ex:

```
//legacy code 
#include "func.h"
func(void) //function in a .c file used in many files

//refactored code
#include "func.h"
func(int a) //all used instances fail(obviously).
```

Is there any way where I can add the new parameter to be adapted in all calls without manually changing all failed instances?

Im using Eclipse IDE for the c project.

Note: I don't want to use "int a" as a global variable to be shared among all files. Just looking for an easy way to do it.

Comment: Just asking you anyway need to call the function like func(5) don't you ? you can do that in c++

Answer (score 2):

No, all of the callers of func must be modified to pass in a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative for the special case in which most calls will give the same value.
You can set up a default value. This will allow you to leave those calls unchanged which would give the default value anyway.
The implementation in C assumes:

a) You will anyway have to edit the calls with non-default value
b) You will anyway have to edit the prototype in the corresponding header
c) You will anyway have to edit the sorce code which defines the function

Here is how to implement a default value in C, based on those assumptions:

func.h, assumed current content:

```
void func(void);
```

func.h, new content:

```
void func(void);
void funcA(int a);
```

func.c, assumed current content:

```
#include "func.h"
void func(void)
{ /* ... */ }
```

func.c, new content:

```
#include "func.h"

static const int iDefaultForFunc = 42;
/* as desired, this is NOT used as global variable */

void func(void)
{
    funcA(iDefaultForFunc);
}

void funcA(int a)
{
    /* ... */
    /* probably some use of a */
}
```

NonDefaultCaller.c:

```
/* somewhere */
funcA(43); /* calling with special value */
```

DefaultCaller.c, no actual need to change:

```
/* somewhere */
func(); /* ends up calling funcA(iDefaultForFunc); */
```